# How to show a list in a dialog in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am running jQuery with in this Javascript function. My problem is that after successful completion, I get a message which I display in an alert dialog.

My message string is something like that "Avinash|Ajay|Rahul..." This is dynamic. Now I want to show these names in a dialog list.

```
function showRemarks(number) {
  $.ajax({
    url : 'PrintRemarks.jsp',
    data : 'COURSE_CODE=' + "<%=course_code%>" + '&TYPE=' + "<%=course_type%>" + '&NUMBER=' + number,
    type : 'post',
    success : function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use JSON instead of `Avinash|Ajay|Rahul`.

Comment: What's a dialog list?

Answer (score 0):

You can show HTML in jQuery Dialog. Please check the link: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form.

So you can add a div in your body and then as per your above example you can place the  list in that container DIV. After that you have initialize tha jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't use gui elements from browser, there is no way to show an (HTML) list in this element. As far as can see you use jquery so there should be also be possible to use jqueryui.
In case you want really really use the element from browser you can format the output text. You just have to use '\t' -a tabsign- and '\n' - a linebreak. Here an example:

```
var msg = "A list:\n\t- Number one\n\t- Number two\n\t\t\t- Number two-one";
alert(msg);
```

I doubt you don't want this...